# “Edit Level” button on mediocre mapper just brings me back to settings

Tags: beat-saber

I am creating a beat saber custom map using Mediocre Mapper (the latest version). I have followed BennyDaBeasts tutorial on this which you can find here:

My problem is that whenever I go to click “edit level”, it doesn’t enter the level editor; it doesn’t throw any errors, but just loads for a very long time and puts me back where I was before. Because no errors were given, I have no idea what’s going on. It is a .ogg, converted using audacity in the same way shown in the video, so converting it again does not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my cover image was named "cover.jpeg" instead of "cover.jpg". I switched it and was able to easily load into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Just used an online converter to change my song file from an mp3 to an ogg and it worked.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't solve anything; I have converted it in audacity exactly how he showed and I have converted it online. Neither worked. Do you have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Run MediocreMapper with administrator privileges. I had the same problem as you, but this solved it.